# NullpointerException on EntityManager using Maven + intelliJ + Tomcat 7 + JPA2

Tags: java, maven, jpa, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception

Hello I am setting up a very simple app using JPA2, I am getting a nullpointer exception when I try to use the EntityManager
I am using:
intellij IDEA
Maven
JPA 2
Servlet 3
Tomcat 7

Here is the structure of my project:
-> http://picpaste.com/screen1-ZKITGaeh.jpg

Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="mymoneyunit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <description>
        Persistence unit for the JPA tutorial of the Hibernate Getting Started Guide
    </description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.mymoney.entities.User</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moneydb" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

UserDAO:

```
package com.mymoney.database;

import com.mymoney.entities.User;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import java.util.List;

public class UserDAO {
    private EntityManager em;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mymoneyunit")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }
    public List<User> findAll() {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = cb.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> user = criteria.from(User.class);

        criteria.select(user).orderBy(cb.asc(user.get("name")));
        return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myMoney</groupId>
    <artifactId>myMoney-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
   <!--     <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- MySQL JDBC connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.27</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tomcat jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.35</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ******* JPA/Hibernate ******** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

HomeController:

```
@WebServlet("/home")
public class HomeController extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doGet");
        UserDAO uDao = new UserDAO();
        List<User> users = uDao.findAll();
        for(User usr : users){
            System.out.println(usr.getEmail());
        }
    }
}
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.mymoney.database.UserDAO.findAll(UserDAO.java:25)
    com.mymoney.controllers.HomeController.doGet(HomeController.java:28)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Nothing is being written to the logs related to the JPA setup :(.

Thank you for the help

UPDATE

I moved the persistence.xml inside the resources/META-INF
Created a new class to manage the entitymanager instead of using the annotation to inject the entitymanager:

```
public class PersistenceManager {
    private static PersistenceManager INSTANCE;
    private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;

    public static PersistenceManager getInstance(){
        if(PersistenceManager.INSTANCE == null){
            PersistenceManager.INSTANCE = new PersistenceManager();
        }    
        return PersistenceManager.INSTANCE;
    }

    private PersistenceManager() {
        emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mymoneyunit");
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }


    public void close() {
        emFactory.close();
    }
}
```

Now I am getting:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Fixed the problem above, checking the mysql jar to be exported in intellij and changing the order of it in the classpath.

Comment: Show the code of HomeController.  How does it get a reference to the dao?

Comment: And also beans.xml. Your pom is not relevant.

Comment: I edited the question and added the details you asked.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unseen offending code lies here :

```
private EntityManager em;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mymoneyunit")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }
    ...
}
```

In above code, the container will not inject the **EntityManager** to your **UserDAO** class because:

1). The **@PersistenceContext** annotation can be used on any CDI bean, EJB, or JSF ManagedBean.

2). This particular **EntityManager** is injected as an **EXTENDED** persistence context, which simply means that the **EntityManager** is created when the **@Stateful** bean is created and destroyed when the **@Stateful** bean is destroyed.

Simply put, the data in the **EntityManager** is cached for the lifetime of the **@Stateful** bean.

The use of **EXTENDED** persistence contexts is only available to **@Stateful** beans.

So, Put this :

```
@Stateful
public class UserDAO {
    private EntityManager em;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mymoneyunit")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }
    ....
}
```

Now your **EntityManager** with name ***mymoneyunit*** will be injected by the container.

**NOTE :** In order to use JavaEE Dependency Injection, you will need to use one of CDI implementations like **JBoss Weld**(in this case you will need to configure as how to use JBoss Weld with Tomcat) OR as Provided by **TomEE**.

Comment: This solution forces me to use EJB witch I dont want. Maybe I can not use the depency injection like I tried.
I changed the implementation to create the EntityManager using a singleton class. it worked, at least I started to get another exception:
org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]

Comment: This means that Hibernate is not able to find the Driver class from your MySQL JDBC Driver JAR. Can you please provide the new StackTrace in place of the Old One.

Comment: I found the problem.
I had to change the order of mysql driver i nthe list and chech to export that.. that fixed.

Comment: @RodrigoDeOliveiraMurta Glad you got it. Don't have any experience with IntelliJ - :)

Comment: @RodrigoDeOliveiraMurta Also it may be because your mysql dependecy scope is "provided" which is not available at runtime. change it to "compile" scope which is available in all build classpaths

Comment: I dont have experience with intelliJ either, this is my first project using it. I am a eclipse guy since ever. but to be honest I am liking a lot intelliJ until now.

About the scope the mysql dependency had no scope. is the provided the default one?

Comment: The comlipe is the default scope :D :D. so it is already there :D

Comment: @RodrigoDeOliveiraMurta, "compile" is the default scope. But since you have given scope for mysql dependency as "provided", it will not be available to the classpath at runtime. May be that is why you got ClassNotFoundException.